# how to have defaultValue set to null on sql for every new provider after migration

Tags: javascript, sql, typescript, nestjs

i have a column in PROVIDER class model which is:

`@Column({ type: DataType.STRING, allowNull: false, }) iban: string;`

what i want is to migrate so when i create a new provider, my iban is automatically set to null.

the following line is the last two migration with iban(including the new migration):

1st MIGRATION:

```
  module.exports = {
up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
  await queryInterface.addColumn('PROVIDER', 'iban', {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    hidden: true,
    });
  },

  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.removeColumn('PROVIDER', 'iban');
  },
};
```

THE NEW MIGRATION:

```
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
  await queryInterface.changeColumn('PROVIDER', 'iban', {
  type: Sequelize.STRING,
  allowNull: true,
  defaultValue: null,
});
await queryInterface.bulkUpdate('PROVIDER', { iban: null }, { 
  iban: 'FR0000000000' });
},

down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
  await queryInterface.bulkUpdate('PROVIDER', { iban: 
  'FR0000000000' }, { iban: null });
await queryInterface.changeColumn('PROVIDER', 'iban', {
  type: Sequelize.STRING,
  allowNull: false,
    });
  },
};
```

this following lines is the new value for iban in provider:

```
proUserFromDto(
proUserDto: ProUserDto,
user: User,
societyAddress: Address,
invoicingAddress?: Address,
): Provider {
const provider = new Provider();
provider.userId = user.id;
provider.tahiti = proUserDto.tahitiNumber;
provider.approved = !!proUserDto.approved;
provider.addressId = societyAddress.id;
provider.invoicingAdressId = invoicingAddress?.id;
provider.iban = null;
return provider;
}
```

here is the error i get:

```
[Nest] 2695  - 20/02/2024 18:05:01   ERROR [UserService] SequelizeValidationError: notNull Violation: Provider.iban cannot be null
createProUserEntity
[Nest] 2695  - 20/02/2024 18:05:01   ERROR [UserService] SequelizeValidationError: notNull Violation: Provider.iban cannot be null
createProUser
[Nest] 2695  - 20/02/2024 18:05:01   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] notNull Violation: Provider.iban cannot be null
SequelizeValidationError: notNull Violation: Provider.iban cannot be null
    at InstanceValidator._validate (/Users/heimo/Documents/dev/tauturu-fare/backend/node_modules/sequelize/src/instance-validator.js:78:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at InstanceValidator._validateAndRunHooks (/Users/heimo/Documents/dev/tauturu-fare/backend/node_modules/sequelize/src/instance-validator.js:111:7)
    at InstanceValidator.validate (/Users/heimo/Documents/dev/tauturu-fare/backend/node_modules/sequelize/src/instance-validator.js:93:12)
    at Provider.save (/Users/heimo/Documents/dev/tauturu-fare/backend/node_modules/sequelize/src/model.js:4076:7)
    at UserService.createProUserEntity (/Users/heimo/Documents/dev/tauturu-fare/backend/src/user/services/user.service.ts:197:25)
    at UserService.createProUser (/Users/heimo/Documents/dev/tauturu-fare/backend/src/user/services/user.service.ts:105:7)
    at /Users/heimo/Documents/dev/tauturu-fare/backend/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-execution-context.js:46:28
    at /Users/heimo/Documents/dev/tauturu-fare/backend/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-proxy.js:9:17
```

i cant get over it :(